# Calls to NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods to download images only works occasionally

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, nsurlconnection

I currently have two `UIImageView`s in my storyboard, one of which downloads my own Facebook profile picture, and the other a friend's profile picture.

[image: Storyboard layout]

However, my issue is that **only 60% of the time this works as expected**, while the other 40% of the times my own profile picture appears where my friend's picture should show in the bottom, while the top box remains empty.  I am unsure whether this is the result of how I call the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods as it downloads or completes view, or the nature of my requests called to Facebook.

I've pasted the condensed version of my two requests to Facebook in `viewDidLoad`, one which gets my own profile pic, and the other to get my friend's pic:

```
// ----- Gets my own profile picture, using requestForMe -----
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    //handle response
    if(!error){
        //Some methods not included for breveity, includes facebookID used below
        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];
        self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        switcher = 1;
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:2.0f];
        NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        if (!urlConnection){
            NSLog(@"Failed to download picture");
        }
    }
}];
// ----- Gets a profile picture of my friend, using requestForMyFriends -----
FBRequest *requestForFriends = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends]; 
[requestForFriends startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        //Other methods not included, including facebookFriendID
        NSURL *friendPictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookFriendID]];
        self.supportImageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        switcher = 2;
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:friendPictureURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:2.0f];
        NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        if (!urlConnection){
            NSLog(@"Failed to download picture");
        }
    }
}];
```

Both requests make calls to the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods, and I use the `switcher` to decide when to load which picture:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // As chuncks of the image are received, we build our data file

    if (switcher == 1) [self.imageData appendData:data];
    if (switcher == 2)[self.supportImageData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    //When the entire image is finished downloading
    if (switcher == 1) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData]; //puts the completed picture into the UI
        self.titleImageView.image = image;
        [self.titleImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    }

    if (switcher == 2) {
        UIImage *supportImage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.supportImageData];
        self.supportImageView.image = supportImage;
        [self.titleImageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two asynchronous processes, both of which can result in having your  `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods in `self` being called. But if they happen at the same time, they're going to step on top of each other (you're presumably using a single `NSMutableData` variable to reference the data being downloaded).

Either create dedicated class that you can instantiate once for each of your two `NSURLConnection` requests (a `NSOperation` based approach, like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), is ideal), or use [`sendAsynchronousRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10) instead. But don't use a single object as the `delegate` for two concurrent `NSURLConnection` requests at the same time.

---

If you wanted to see a minimalist download operation, it might look like:

```
//  NetworkOperation.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void(^DownloadCompletion)(NSData *data, NSError *error);

@interface NetworkOperation : NSOperation

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(DownloadCompletion)completionBlock;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, copy) DownloadCompletion downloadCompletionBlock;

@end
```

and

```
//  NetworkOperation.m

#import "NetworkOperation.h"

@interface NetworkOperation () <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isFinished)  BOOL finished;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *data;

@end

@implementation NetworkOperation

@synthesize finished  = _finished;
@synthesize executing = _executing;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(DownloadCompletion)downloadCompletionBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.url = url;
        self.downloadCompletionBlock = downloadCompletionBlock;

        _executing = NO;
        _finished = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation related stuff

- (void)start
{
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url];
    NSAssert(request, @"%s: requestWithURL failed for URL '%@'", __FUNCTION__, [self.url absoluteString]);
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataDelegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    self.data = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        [connection cancel];
        self.executing = NO;
        self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    [self.data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (self.downloadCompletionBlock) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.downloadCompletionBlock(self.data, nil);
            self.downloadCompletionBlock = nil;
        }];
    }

    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished = YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.downloadCompletionBlock) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.downloadCompletionBlock(nil, error);
            self.downloadCompletionBlock = nil;
        }];
    }

    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished = YES;
}

@end
```

And then, when you wanted to use it, it might look like:

```
NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;

// ----- Gets my own profile picture, using requestForMe -----
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    //handle response
    if(!error) {
        //Some methods not included for breveity, includes facebookID used below
        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];

        [networkQueue addOperation:[[NetworkOperation alloc] requestWithURL:pictureURL completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                self.meImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
        }]];
    }
}];
// ----- Gets a profile picture of my friend, using requestForMyFriends -----
FBRequest *requestForFriends = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends]; 
[requestForFriends startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(!error){
        //Other methods not included, including facebookFriendID
        NSURL *friendPictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookFriendID]];

        [networkQueue addOperation:[[NetworkOperation alloc] requestWithURL:friendPictureURL completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                self.friendImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
        }]];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Rob.  When you mention a dedicated class that instantiate once for each of the requests, could you clarify a bit more on that (or if you know of any write ups or guides I could look more into this it'd be awesome).

Comment: @daspianist If you google "NSURLConnection NSOperationQueue" you'll see tons of link (though not any single definitive one I'm comfortable referring you to). You might just want to consider using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). I've thrown together some examples (including an [operation-based solution](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-operation) and a [non-operation-based solution](https://github.com/robertmryan/download-manager)), but I'd really suggest you consider using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) before writing your own.